# Deploying JSf 2.0 app in tomcat 5.5

Tags: jsf, tomcat6, jsf-2, tomcat5.5

I have developed a JSF 2.0 application and tested it on Apache Tomcat 6.0. The problem is that the official server can only have version 5.5 installed. So I tried to deploy it as it was but I kept getting the JasperException. I figured out that the problem probably lies with the standard.jar and jstl.jar. How can I deploy it then? How to downgrade the application? 
Thanks for any help, links or tutorials.
Best Regards.

Comment: In the future that you retrieve exceptions and don't understand them, then you should post the **full exception and stacktrace** in your question.

Comment: Note, that you need extra effort to get method calls with parameters inside your action="..." etc. tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSF2.0 requires Tomcat 6.0 or later.

If you use the [JSF-RI 1.2](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/download.html), you can run JSF 1.2 with tomcat 5.5

**EDITED**:

I read that in version 5.5.20 it doesn't work properly. Tomcat 5.5.17 and Tomcat 5.0.28 are fine with JSF1.2

Answer (score 0):

I have used Mojarra 2.0.3-b03 on Tomcat 5.5.28 and it works well so far. All basic facelet tags work fine so far (h:dataTable, f:ajax, etc.)
Currently trying to use RichFaces 4 (still under development though) but seems lot of components not ready yet.